# Sum of (actual value - average value across all rows) in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have a table of statisctics:

```
Page | Action | Time
--------------------
Home | Logon  |  12
Home | Logon  |  11
Home | Search |  20
About| Comment|  10
```

I can write a query to get the average Action time for each page:

```
select Page, avg(Time) from statistics group by Page
```

But I'd like to be a bit more clever. In order to highlight which pages have the most *slow* actions on, I'd like to get the sum of (time - average time for all actions on all pages). I could do this in separate queries:

```
select avg(Time) from statistics
-> 15
select Page, sum(Time - 15) from statistics group by Page
```

Question is, is there a way to do this in a single query?

Obviously `select Page, sum(Time - avg(Time)) from statistics group by Page` doesn't work. Oracle throws "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function".

Comment: Won't this always be 0, unless you filter it?

Comment: A page could have all of its actions take longer than the global average, in which case the result would be positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Window functions:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        Page, 
        AVG(Time) OVER(PARTITION BY Page) - AVG(Time) OVER() AS Variance
FROM    Statistics
```

And to expand slightly you can then get many different averages in the one query:

```
SELECT  Page, 
        Action,
        Time,
        AVG(Time) OVER(PARTITION BY Page, Action) AS AverageActionTime,
        AVG(Time) OVER(PARTITION BY Page) AS AveragePageTime,
        AVG(Time) OVER() AS AverageTime
FROM    Statistics
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/42a5f/8

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery to calculate the average time:

```
select  stat.Page
,       sum(stat.Time - avg_stat.time) 
from    statistics stat
cross join    
        (
        select  avg(Time) as time
        from    statistics
        ) avg_stat
group by 
        stat.Page
```